# Passing data to server using javascript securelly?

Tags: javascript, security

At the moment I'm passing data to node js server via javascript and the reason i must do this is because I'm using socket.io so I emit the data from the client. 
There's a method on javascript to store data on a div and the data is invisible on the div `$('#divID').data('name','value');` but still the user can see the data when i'm storing it and when I'm sending it. Is there a way I can store and emit the data via javascript the way that user can't change or see it?
It's a 16-digit user ID.

Comment: So this means that if I must pass the value through javascript there's no way to pass it safely?

Comment: What level of security are you looking for? Visually hiding data from the user is easy. Hiding data from a savy user who knows how to work his browser is much harder, but still possible - just maybe not from JS.

Comment: Same answer :) An average user won't see it if it is invisible, but Javascript can always be seen by parsing source code.

Comment: It's kind of an auction site in where the user clicks on a bid button that sends to server the "new bid" message, this message must contain the user id, if the user changes it's ID for other user's ID then the server will think that the one who's bidding is the second one. Is there another way?
To send the message I use the command `socket.emit('new bid' {"itemID": itemID, "userID": userID});`

Comment: To identify more securely the users, you should use PHP and create one session per user.

Comment: @Lambic I have done this already, I'm getting the user id in php from session, but to send it to socket server i must pass it through javascript, can't think of another way

Comment: you need to give each user a secret only they know and need to place a bid. that way, you can't bid for anyone else without the secret. the user doesn't need to know or care about the secret, only his device. you should also periodically change the secret.

Comment: Then you can compare the userID with the PHP one before it is sent. Or after.

Comment: So if I do like this: `if(userID!=="<?php echo $_SESSION['userID'];?>"){userID="<? echo $_SESSION['userID'];?>"}` Then I should be fine right?

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code but at first sight, it looks good. Has to be tested, anyway. (personnaly, I would ban an user who's trying to spoof his ID). You should also verify the bid is a legitimate number (ie not string, not negative, etc.)

Comment: @Lambic Actually, thinking better the user can also see this condition statement and change it too if it's javascript. Maybe the only way after all is to set a secret for each user when bidding. Maybe hashing their id and storing in the database

Comment: Yes, since it's into a javascript code, it can be changed. The comparison should be in plain PHP and after the server received data.

Comment: @Lambic since the onclick event is set in javascript there's no way to compare this in php then. The socket.emit can't be done in php(at least i think). I use socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in essence is meant to be publicly viewable. Anybody with the knowledge of Javascript will be able to see everything that you are doing. So, you will have to continue to send it to the server before it can go to the database.

Comment: The id is already in the database, I don't mind if the user sees it, actually everyone knows their own id, the question is, how to pass it to server with `socket.emit('message', userID)`, without letting the user change it?

Comment: feed a temp and per-user-unique secret from php to sockets and the client, check for that secret before accepting a bid. think of the old spy movies where the other contact has to finish a secret sentence before the briefcase is handed over...

Comment: @dandavis that's a really great solution. I wish there was a simpler way thou ^^, but this will do, thank You!

Comment: @dandavis make this an answer so I can accept it =]